# Adding a mysql constraint or trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, constraints

I have a quick question about Triggers and Unique constraints in MySQL. I'll give a quick example.

I have two tables, "Account" and "Users". The relationship between these two tables is 1 (Account) to many (Users). So if you pull up an Account table with a unique id you'll come across multiple Users for that one account. The User table has a column in it called 'user_type'. 'user_type' can either be 'admin', 'guest', 'trial'. The "Account" has to have a user that has 'admin' as a 'user_type'. It can only have 1 'admin' per Account.

So, is there a way to add a unique constraint so that any Account can only have 1 'admin' user_type to it? Or does it have to be a trigger since it's MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a more flexible system if you implemented Groups rather than making this an attribute of the user table.

With that said, obviously you could enforce your business rule with a Trigger.

There is however a way you could use a constraint, at least in a partial sense.

Create a table:

```
AccountAdmin
------------
account_admin_id (pk)
account_id (fk) Add unique constraint
user_id (fk)
```

Once you have the unique index on account_id, you enforce your rule that there can be only one admin per account.

When you create a user who is an admin, then you will need to insert a row into AccountAdmin.  The constraint will prevent you from doing that, should an admin already exist.

With that said, in order to change from one admin to another, you would need to delete the row from this table first, then add the new one.

Once you begin to consider the type of code you need to support a function like "change admin" or "promote to admin", triggers are even less desirable in my opinion.

In regards to Triggers:

Having done a lot of work on systems where there is a requirement that the system be scalable to "n" users, one of the the things I've learned to avoid is creating bottlenecks at the data persistence level.  MySQL triggers and stored procs are intrinsically not scalable.

You are concentrating a bottleneck within the database and limiting concurrency.  There is no way to do this exercise in a Trigger without locking the table to insure that when you query to insure there are no admins for your organization, another query doesn't insert an admin before you do.  It's also an anti-pattern to have to throw a database exception and handle that, for something that is not an error at all (ie. an admin exists already).

If there is a way for you to move this code into the application (and in this case, there is) then that is a more scalable solution.

Comment: Let's assume that we're past the point of being able to add new tables. Without this table is a trigger the only path I have available?

Comment: How could you possibly be past the point of adding a table that relates 2 existing tables by their keys?

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make sure each Account has exactly one admin user to have a foreign key to the User row that is the admin.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  account_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE Account (
  account_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  admin_user_id INT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Account ADD FOREIGN KEY (admin_user_id) 
  REFERENCES Users (user_id);

ALTER TABLE Users ADD FOREIGN KEY (account_id) 
  REFERENCES Account(account_id);

INSERT INTO Users () VALUES ();
SET @uid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO Account (admin_user_id) VALUES (@uid);
UPDATE Users SET account_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE user_id = @uid;
```

Making sure the users for each account are limited to exactly one admin and I assume multiple users of other types is a little trickier. But with virtual columns in MySQL 5.7 we can do it.

```
ALTER TABLE Users 
  ADD COLUMN user_type ENUM('admin', 'guest', 'trial') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'guest',
  ADD COLUMN is_admin TINYINT(1) AS (IF(user_type='admin',1,NULL)) STORED,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (account_id, is_admin);

SELECT * FROM Users;
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | account_id | user_type | is_admin |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |          1 | guest     |     NULL |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+

INSERT INTO Users (account_id, user_type) VALUES (1, 'admin');

SELECT * FROM Users;
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | account_id | user_type | is_admin |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
|       1 |          1 | guest     |     NULL |
|       2 |          1 | admin     |        1 |
+---------+------------+-----------+----------+

INSERT INTO Users (account_id, user_type) VALUES (1, 'admin');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'account_id'
```

The UNIQUE KEY on the virtual column ignores NULLs. So any number of guest or trial users can exist, and they all get represented by NULL in the virtual column. But one admin user per account can exist with the value 1 in that virtual column.